# How to get a count of leaf nodes?

Tags: counters, forest, trees

I'm new to LaTeX, and am working on a tree using `forest`. Is there any way I can find the total number of nodes in my tree which have NO child nodes?

I've tried searching Google and Stack Exchange, but because of my very limited knowledge of LaTeX (started using it yesterday) I don't know what exact terms to use in my search.

I found `\xcount`, but I don't understand how it works and haven't seen it used in the application I'm looking for.

EDIT: The nodes which I desire to count have one of three style keys, perhaps I could somehow count the occurrences of these keys and then add them together?

Code: https://github.com/duncanjoly13/langtex/blob/main/main.tex

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) because helping you out is much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can use the aggregate function "count" with condition "n children=0".

Comment: @SebGlav, thanks for your welcome, I'll remember this

Comment: @SašoŽivanović, I can't seem to find any documentation about this function, would it be used like ```/count{n children=0}```?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the tree preamble will count the leaf nodes:

```
tempcounta/.count={filter={tree}{n_children("")==0}},
```

Aggregate function `.count` takes a nodewalk as an argument (manual, 3.13). As there is no primary nodewalk which only visits the leaves, we need to `filter` (manual, 3.8.4) them out from the `tree` using the condition `n_children("")==0`.

The number of leaves is now stored in the `tempcounta` register. This simply prints it out to the terminal:

```
typeout={Number of leaves: \forestregister{tempcounta}},
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help